# Get full keyboard access state for external keyboards in accessibility

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, accessibility

I need to get the state of this switch in accessibility settings.

I searched in docs and web, but could not find any function, that will represent this.

None of the following functions works

```
UIAccessibility.isGrayscaleEnabled
UIAccessibility.isSpeakSelectionEnabled
UIAccessibility.isClosedCaptioningEnabled
UIAccessibility.isSwitchControlRunning
UIAccessibility.isAssistiveTouchRunning
UIAccessibility.isDarkerSystemColorsEnabled
UIAccessibility.isVideoAutoplayEnabled
UIAccessibility.isGuidedAccessEnabled
UIAccessibility.isOnOffSwitchLabelsEnabled
UIAccessibility.isReduceTransparencyEnabled
UIAccessibility.isShakeToUndoEnabled
UIAccessibility.isBoldTextEnabled
UIAccessibility.isReduceMotionEnabled
UIAccessibility.isInvertColorsEnabled
UIAccessibility.isVoiceOverRunning
UIAccessibility.isMonoAudioEnabled
UIAccessibility.isSpeakScreenEnabled
```

[image: Accessibility settings iOS]